# Dajngo model foreign field with conditional

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say i have a movie related database and two fields:`movie` and `person`. `person` model can consist of directors, actors and writers and has fields `id`, `name`, `profession`.
I know that we can create `ForeignKey` inside of `movie` model, pointing to `person` model, and my question is can fields like `actor`, `director` and `writer` be created or specified inside of  `movie` model, having pointer to `person`model or `NULL` if that id'd person in not this field relates to?

Comment: Make a model `Person` add a field to it which denotes the type like actor, director, etc. Have models like `Actor`, etc. which would have a one to one field with the `Person` model.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat in this case how to connect `Actor` model with actor `role` row inside of `Person` model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
All you need do is add the attribute null=true in your model

```
user = models.Foreignkey(person,...., null=True)
```